# Problem with Response asihtttprequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, response, asihttprequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:year1 forKey:@"year"];
[request setPostValue:appy_level forKey:@"appy_level"];
[request setPostValue:reasons forKey:@"reasons"];
[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"country"];
[request setPostValue:city forKey:@"city"];
[request setPostValue:sex forKey:@"sex"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
NSLog(@"response -%@",[request responseString]);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
}
```

any idea why this code return (null) i mean response is null? and this requestFinised: method isnt working even i write[requestsetDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished)];
method too.I am confuesed right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `NSLog` won't work because you start your request as `asynchronous`.

You chould try putting `NSLog(@"finished");` in `-requestFinished:` to check if page is loading or not. It can be an error in your server file (e.g. php fatal error).

Comment: well i try it now nop the method doesnt call if i am right. so finished never shown.

Comment: It's very strange because I use ASIFormDataRequest in my app and it works... Did you check your URL?

Comment: yes mate i give up using it and i rewrite my php with xml i think i should get response at least :D thanks for patience and helping

Comment: No problem, if you have any questions, write them here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request data] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", response);

Comment: well i doesnt work i give up for that response now i am re writing my php file with xml i am going to use nsxmlparser maybe its better mate thanks